# Data Validation in Tableau

Tags: testing, automated-tests, tableau-api

I am looking for ways to validate data that tableau generates. I know we cannot access elements from the tableau server itself but has someone approached in some way to tackle the data validation for the reports? I am very much interested in learning what type of testing is possible around tableau and its reports.

Thanks in Advance,
RV

Comment: Can you give some example of what data you want to validate in Tableau?

Comment: So views are created from the database tables which serves as datasource to the Tableau. Some values remain same but some may be a combination of views or there may be some calculation involved on the fields in tableau. So lets say A B C are columns where one of the bar chart value is the result of Sum(A,B) this calculation is not present in the view but as a part of tableau so I want to validate the values/data that shows up in the chart basically. Its very hard to explain though

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are reading in data from a view and performing a calculation on it in Tableau. Are you trying to validate the result of the calculation? If so, then against what? What is your source of "right" to compare with?

Comment: Expected data would be from the database + manually calculated values which will be output from tableau and actual will be the tableau crosstab. So if in database I have A=20, B=10, C=30 and tableau shows Avg(A,B)=15, my expected data becomes 15 which I will calculate from the database values and will try to match this in the crosstab. So crosstab should give me 15 too.

Answer (score 0):

We have a testing group that follow behind our workbook developers and test functionality and validity of calculations. One of their primary methods is to examine (sometimes download to Excel) the underlying data which should include fields from the originating data source in addition to the results of calculated fields.